# Are old fashion photomultipliers used in LHC experiments?

Tags: large-hadron-collider, experimental-technology

Are any [photomultipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomultiplier) used in any of LHC detectors? Or are only semiconductor devices used?

If yes, then where?

Comment: You should be aware that PMTs come in a variety of sizes and form factors, and that modern ones can be very small indeed and come packaged in groups. One experiment I'm on uses a 64PMTs-in-one-module device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, photomultipliers are in use in calorimeters which use Cerenkov light to detect the passage of particles. An example is in this [preprint](http://cdsweb.cern.ch/record/1358695/files/CR2007_083.pdf) of the Castor detector at CMS in LHC.

> Charged particles penetrating the CASTOR calorimeter will generate showers in the tungsten absorber plates.
>   These particle showers are sampled by using the Cherenkov effect. Quartz plates are the active medium to generate
>   the Cherenkov light. They are in the form of thin plates inclined by 45± with respect to the beam axis in order
>   to maximize the Cherenkov light. Cherenkov light generated by the charged particles carries the particle-related
>   information. In the CASTOR calorimeter the R5380Q PMT series of Hamamatsu will be used to read out the
>   Cherenkov light (see Table 1 for CASTOR PMT specifications). The Cherenkov light produced in the quartz
>   plates will be transmitted to the PMTs by the mediation of the air filled light guides.

If you go to the document [search page of CERN](http://cdsweb.cern.ch/collection/Articles%20&%20Preprints?ln=en) and search for photomultipliers and CMS you will find many references, though most behind paywalls. This is how I got the preprint above.